# Is there information material to promote specific Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I am looking for anything like flyers, handouts, articles and presentations to promote and inform about specific Stack Exchange sites. The material should include at least some basic introduction, not just a simple banner or tweet. Have some communities created any such material to share and build on? We'd like to promote [Libraries and Information Science](http://libraries.stackexchange.com/), which has a very specific audience. I'm sure there are other Stack Exchange sites with specific audiences that first needed to be reached by targeted offline media. How have those sites accomplished this?

Comment: how about creating a post on meta linking to it? oh wait... :)

Comment: @ajax333221 well, this *is*  a post on meta, isn't it? What's your point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) had a [pamphlet](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/english-se-pamphlet-hang-up-or-hand-out-to-your-friends-and-classmates) designed by [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) (Stack Exchange's resident designer). [French Language & Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/) obtained a [similar pamphlet](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/promotion-de-french-language-and-usage-promoting-french-language-and-usage) with text that we provided, typeset by Jin.

1. Start a thread on your meta.
2. Collect inputs, settle on material.
3. Demonstrate that there are people willing to hand out the material, so it's worth the effort.
4. Ask Community representatives for help with design (generally, moderators handle this part — you should have moderators in a few days).

Comment: Thanks! I hoped to get more than this small pamphlets but nevermind... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is on a case-by-case basis. Do you have a particular type of material in mind or a particular event or use case you'd like to have this material for?

The best thing to do is to post your idea on your own site's meta. Maybe someone in your community has a knack for graphic design and can whip something up for you. If it's for an event where you'll be representing the site in a more formal way, there's a chance that SE designer Jin can design something specific for your event (given adequate notice, of course). Even if it's just something you want to have lying around, there is still a chance SE can help out with it, or that someone else on your site will be willing to come up with the material.

And as always, the more details you can provide about what you'd like to see and how you want to use it, the better your chances for success.